# JPA: Validate fetched field against an Enum

Tags: java, validation, enums, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity like so:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyTable", schema = "test")
@Getter @Setter
public class PurgeSystemsEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "system_name", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String systemName;
.
.
}
```

How do I validate that the string obtained from DB (*like when doing a `.findAll()`*) in `systemName` field is one of the possible options defined in the **Enum** `System` :

```java
    public static enum System {
        PROD, DEV, QA;
    }
```

So, If a row is fetched with `systemName` value being 'STAGING', it should throw an exception immediately.

Is there some elegant way to do this?

Comment: You can define an ENUM within your class! By default when your value will not map to the ENUM value, it should return IllegalArgumentException, similarly you can also handle that exception in ENUM itself

Comment: I believe setting the type to your enum should work: private System systemName;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the field type to the enum.

```
@Column(name = "system_name", nullable = false, length = 255)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private System systemName;
```

This will cause an error if you encounter a value not defined in the enum.

You also have to set `EnumType.STRING` explicitly, as it defaults to `EnumType.ORDINAL` which would correspond to the enum ordinal value instead of the name

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the error part ? Can I rig it somehow to through a custom exception?

Comment: I don't believe that you can change the error message, though it should be pretty clear. From a different question: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value for enum class com.a.b.c.d.Class$Status: OK`

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own method in `ENUM`

***Something like this***

```
public static MyEnum fromValue(String value) {
    for (MyEnum b : MyEnum.values()) {
      if (b.value.equals(value)) {
        return b;
      }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");
  }
```

Alternatively, if your Enum is part of your class, I think , Java should automatically handle and throw IllegalArgumentException if the value cannot be mapped !

Comment: How do I tie this method to the entity automatically ? Such that this check is done automatically when a row is fetched ?

Comment: You can define this ENUM as part of your Entity class itself !